# Is there an equivalent of cd - for cp or mv?

Tags: linux, bash, file-transfer, zsh

In Bash and similar shells `cd -` changes the current directory to a previously visited one. It's often very handy. I wonder if there is similar shorthand for copying or moving files, like:

```
~/project-a/ $ cd ../project-b
~/project-b/ $ cp Makefile LICENSE - # this won't work, hence the question
```

I'd be also happy with `zsh` specific answers.

Comment: With bash: Instead of `-` press `Esc` and then `.` to get from last command its last argument (here: `../project-b`).

Comment: That's true @Cyrus, but in the example the intention is to copy from `project-b` to `project-a`.

Comment: @Cyrus, I was always aware that bash has some Emacs-like key bindings and am a heavy Emacs user myself. I was always happily using the general line movement keys of emacs on the shell (C-a etc.). But your comment prompted me to actually look for key bindings in `man bash`. Holy moly... it *really* is Emacs-like, complete with the kill ring, the mark semantics (C-space) etc. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your shell has `cd -`, then it will likely have either the special variable `$OLDPWD` and/or the shortcut `~-` for the directory you've been in previously.

```
cp Makefile LICENSE "$OLDPWD/"

cp Makefile LICENSE ~-

cat ~-/Makefile
```

Indeed the POSIX shell language (upon which ksh/bash/zsh are built) [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) that `cd -` should be equal to `cd "$OLDPWD"`.

Comment: Tilde expansion has a lot more to it even than that.  For an additional taste, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286628/135943 and that doesn’t even cover home directories.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use *shell backquotes*.

They act like a subshell : the command in the backquotes is executed first, and its output is placed as argument of the main command.

```
~/folderA$ cd ../folderB  
~/folderB$ cp Makefile `cd -`  
# gets expended to "cp Makefile ~/folderA"
```

Comment: No, the command `cd -` outputs nothing, so \`cd -\` expands to the empty string.  Try the command % echo \`cd -\` to verify.   You would need to use something like % echo \`cd -; pwd\` ...

Comment: @NealYoung: It seems that there’s something wrong with your shell. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_05) says “When a <hyphen-minus> is used as the operand [to `cd`], this shall be equivalent to the command: `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`, which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its name.” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says “An argument of **``-``** is converted to **`$OLDPWD`** before the directory change is attempted.  If a non-empty directory name from **`CDPATH`** is used, or if **``-``** is the first argument, and the directory change is successful, the absolute pathname of the new working directory is written to the standard output.”

Comment: @Nathanael C.: But please use `"$(cd -)"`.

Comment: There's only "something wrong" if the shell claims POSIX compliance, and I think it's perfectly normal for shells that weren't invoked as /bin/sh and aren't specifically trying to emulate a POSIX shell to implement their language in whatever way they want...

Comment: @G-Man: It seems that under fish, csh, and tcsh, the command `cd -` doesn't print anything, but under bash and sh it does.